# Accordian not working with all my data

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using this according plugin [link text](http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-3/) the 3rd one down...3: Non-accordion (standard expandable menu) and each li looks like this

```
<li>
<a href="#">Burswood Dome - Burswood Wa, Australia</a>
        2010-10-04
        <ul class="acitem">
              <br><input id="yes_song1" name="yes" type="radio" value="song[1]" />
              Yes
              <br><input id="no_song1" name="no" type="radio" value="song[1]" />
              No
                <li>master of puppets</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Any reason why the accordion is not working because if i use just li with text it works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that LIs are the only children of the UL element. Also, even though you shouldn't have a `br` element as a direct child of a `ul`, you should write `<br />` instead of `<br>`.

Comment: what do you mean ...do i have too much html there

Comment: A `UL` element is an unordered list. Browsers expect there to be `LI` s (list items) directly beneath them. When you put something like a `BR` directly beneath a `UL`, the browser will probably throw errors at you. The reason why the accordion is breaking is probably related to this. Make your `UL` proper HTML and I'm sure it will figure it out.

Comment: Agreed - both `ul` and `ol` tags **must** have `li` tags, and **only** `li` tags, as their children. No `div`, `br`, `span` or any other tags (or standard text) is allowed. These must be within the `li` tags.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the script is breaking is because http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

> The markup of your accordion container needs pairs of headers and content panels:

So it should be alternating elements, one for a header, one for content. Mine is a pair of divs, with css class names accHeader and accContent, like thus:

```
<div class='accHeader'>... blah blah blah ... </div>
<div class='accContent'> ... blah blah ... </div>
<div class='accHeader'>... blah blah blah ... </div>
<div class='accContent'> ... blah blah ... </div>
<div class='accHeader'>... blah blah blah ... </div>
<div class='accContent'> ... blah blah ... </div>
```

And my accordion works just fine. Also, bear in mind that you can nest whatever you want inside a div. Including `<br />`s

Comment: rather than edit, I'll add a comment for future readers benefit: I just realized that he had the question originally tagged as "jquery-accordion" but he's using a thirdparty accordion control, not the jquery-ui one, which is what I associated the two to mean. So my answer is not 100% correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in my case it was because I had used the usual 'Script Manager" instead  of using the "Toolkit Script Manager". Try swapping and it might work fine. Also if I am right 'Toolkit Script Manager' is the superset of 'Script Manager'

Hope I was able to help.